# macOS failure to compile cpprestsdk

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, clang, cpprest-sdk

I am getting the following error when I try to compile [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk):

> /Users/radu/work/casablanca/Release/libs/websocketpp/websocketpp/transport/asio/connection.hpp:425:24: error: no matching function for call to 'make_shared'
>               m_strand = lib::make_shared(
>                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:4808:1: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template
>         parameter '_Tp'
>   make_shared(_Args&& ...__args)

I have `maxOS High Sierra` with:

```
$ g++ --version    
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. The fix is simple, try this:
go to your `websocketpp` folder, switch to `master branch` and `pull` the latest changes. It worked for me.